# Why can't we do some basic algebra in tensor calculus?

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation

I have a very, very stupid question on the basics of tensor calculus.
Consider
$R_{ij} = 0$.

1)If I expand the ricci tensor

$R_{ij}= g^{lm}R_{iljm}=0$.

Now, my question is that, ***why*** can't we divide this by either the riemann tensor or the metric tensor to get either,

$R_{iljm}= 0$ (which is wrong)    and $g^{lm}$ = $0$ (which is meaningless).

2)Also, if we "transpose" a covariant / contravariant tensor to the other side of the equation, does the position of the index change? Or is is it just wrong to transpose a tensor? More specifically, for ARBITRARY tensors, if,

$A_{bc} L^{mn}$= $K^{mn}_{bc}$, Then which of the following is correct:

$A_{bc}$= $K^{mn}_{bc}L_{mn}$                      (The index becomes covariant for L)

$L^{mn} = K^{mn}_{bc}A^{bc}$           (The index becomes contravariant for A)

Or

$L_{mn}= \frac{K_{bc}^{mn}}{A_{bc}}$,

And the similar expression for $A_{bc}$.

I know this is an idiotic question, and even I get annoyed thinking about it, but please bear with me.

Comment: You are using the Einstein notation, this is a $sum$ on $l,m$ indices, with $l,m$ in [0,1,2,3].

Comment: assuming a background in basic linear algebra, think in terms of matrices (which are rank-2 tensors): not all matrices are invertible, and those that are generally aren't orthogonal (ie $A^t\not=A^{-1}$)

Comment: How can you divide by a tensor?

Answer (score 3):

The algebraic rule that if $xy=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$ does hold for tensor products: if you had $a^x b_y = 0$ you could conclude that $a^x = 0$ or $b_y = 0$. But there's no such rule for contractions like $a^x b_x$. For example suppose $a$ and $b$ written out in components were $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ respectively.

You can't just move a variable to the other side of an algebraic equation; you have to multiply both sides by an inverse of some sort. Depending on $L$, you might be able to define $\bar L$ to be its inverse in the sense that $L^{pq} \bar L_{pq} = 1$, and then multiply both sides by $\bar L$ and contract to get $A_{bc} = K^{mn}_{bc} \bar L_{mn}$. But I can't recall seeing a tensor inverse defined this way. $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $g^{\mu\nu}$ are matrix inverses, but $g_{\mu\nu} g^{\mu\nu} \ne 1$ (unless the underlying vector space has dimension 1).